# Generating n number of different files in python

Tags: python

In my code I create a text file of random numbers. But I am wondering if it is possible to generate multiple files, each time with different ranges for the random numbers within a for loop.

I have an idea for how to implement this, but I'm not sure how to call the file I make each time
testn, with n being the current value of n. So I would have files: test1, test2 and so on.

My implementation so far is:

```
numberOfFiles = 5 #set this to the number of files you want to make

for n in range(numberOfFiles):
    newFile = open('testn.txt', 'w') #if possible I want to create a file each time and call it testn, where n is the current value of n.

    x = []

    for i in range(10): #number of lines in each file
        x.append(random.randint(0,60 + (n * 10))

    for val in range(len(x)):
        newFile.write(str(x[val]) + "\n")

    newFile.close()
```

Comment: What is the output its giving?

Comment: btw Please prefer to use `with open(...) as newFile:`

Comment: What is the difference between what I have and what you have suggested @quamrana ?

Comment: You can dispense with the `newFile.close()` and your files are automatically closed, even if there is an exception.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newFile = open('test' + str(n) + '.txt', 'w')`

or in python3.6+:

`newfile = open(f'test{n}.txt','w')`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
filename = "test" + str(n) + ".txt"
newFile = open(filename, 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you it will create 5 text files each file contain 10 random numbers between range that you define in your code:

```
import random
numberOfFiles = 5
for n in range(numberOfFiles):
    filename = "test" + str(n) + ".txt"
    newFile = open(filename, 'w')
    x = []
    for i in range(10): #number of lines in each file
        x.append(random.randint(0,60 + (n * 10)))

    for val in range(len(x)):
        newFile.write(str(x[val]) + "\n")
    newFile.close()
```